# Microsoft Access is inserting wrong values in table

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2010, record

I am fairly new at Microsoft Access and I came upon a error which I can't seem to resolve. I create 2 seperate form which are LOGIN and LOGOUT, which essentially will handle all the employee interactions throughout the day with basic functionality.

[image: Relationship]

[image: Login form]

Incase you needed to see my relationships or login form to get a idea of what I am doing.

My login button on click

```vb
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
    'add record to database
    Dim empID As Integer
    Dim logDate As Date
    Dim logTime As String
    logTime = Time
    logDate = Date
    empID = Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(0)

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_workShift(employeeID, logTypeID, logDate, logTime) " & _
     " Values(" & empID & ", 1, #" & logDate & "#, '" & logTime & "')"
End Sub
```

My problem is whenever I login or logout with a employee it seem to create a duplicate of somekind with a different employee number but same first and last name.

[image]

As you can see, employee ID 38 and 40 should not exist, but they were duplicated from 2 and 4? any reason why this is happening? any help will be appreciated

Comment: The code you are showing us inserts into `tbl_workShift`, not into `tbl_employee`. So this code cannot be responsible for the duplicates in `tbl_employee`.

Comment: That's the only code the button contains. What else could effect it?

Comment: could my Queries that help assist with the form, cause this issue?

Comment: Is your form tied to your table? It seems like it..Otherwise I see no way these records could be getting into the table unless you're manually adding them.

Comment: stupid question. How do I check? if you are talking about the form propriety record source then no, but it is tied to my qry_login

Comment: Clear your table out and start over is my best advice at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DataEntry` property of a form is set to true or if you open the form with `DataMode:=acFormAdd` the form will open on a new, empty record, and every entry will be made to this new record.

Make sure to open the form on the right record by selecting the right employee, before editing an employee.

If you are using a combo-box for the selection of employees, make sure NOT to set the Control Source of this control, because you don't want to save the selected value. You want to use it only programmatically.

If you want to have a "pure" data editing and entry form set its properties as follows:

- Default View: Single Form
- Allow Form View: Yes
- Allow Datasheet View: No
- Allow PivotTable View: No
- Allow PivotChart View: No
- Scroll Bars: Neither
- Record Selectors: No
- Navigation Buttons: No
- Border Style: Thin
- Record Source: tbl_employee
- Allow Filters: No
- Allow Edits: Yes
- Allow Deletions: No
- Allow Additions: No
- Data Entry: No

And open it like this

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_employee"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_employee", WhereCondition:="employeeID=" & _
    Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(0), DataMode:=acFormEdit
```

These properties make the form look neat and make sure that you cannot navigate to another record by mistake.

Also you should make a distinction between login and editing employees. The login form should not be allowed to change the employee records.

Comment: I am still having 1 tiny issue, if I got 2 employee in my dropdownlist, and I decide to close the form while its on the first one. Everything will work fine, but if I close it while on the 2nd employee, it seem to  override the first one with the information from the second. Any reason why its doing this?

Comment: This is because you have tied the dropdown to the employees table (either directly or via some query). As I've stated earlier, leave the `ControlSource` property of the dropdown empty, because you don't want it to make changes to the current record. Instead use the value of the dropdown in the `AfterUpdate` event in order to select an employee record. Better don't set the `RecordSource` property of the login form at all. Use the value of the dropdown in order to open an employee in another form.